# relation between tables Laravel

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, laravel-relations

I have 3 tables one for courses and second table for classes and the other table for categories which categories can have multiple classes. so I want to show list of courses with classe_name and category name.
I make pivot table between classes and categories which also contain course name, but I can't show catgory name from table categories and I don't know if this is the correct way

//method to show courses

```
public function index()
{
        
   $categories=Course_category::all();
   return view('teacher.courses')->with('categories',$categories);
}
```

**blade**

```
     @foreach ($categories->classe as $item)
                    {{$item->category_name}}
     @endforeach
```

**categorie model**

```
     protected $table = 'categories';
            protected $fillable =['id','category_name','categorie_image'];
    
    
            /**
             * The roles that belong to the Course_category
             *
             * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
             */
    
            public function classe(){
    
                return $this -> belongsToMany('App\Classe','classe_categorie','categorie_id','classe_id');
            }
```

**classe model**

```
 protected $table = 'classes';
    protected $fillable=['id','classe_name','classe_image'];
    public function course_categorie() {

        return $this -> belongsToMany('App\Course_category','classe_categorie','classe_id','categorie_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through classes, not categories:

```
 @foreach ($categories->classe as $item)
    {{$item->category_name}}
 @endforeach
```

It should be

```
 @foreach ($categories as $item)
    {{$item->classe->classe_name}}
    {{$item->category_name}}
 @endforeach
```

As you want to show classes, why don't you collect all `Classe`s in the controller and start from there? Unless you want to group by categories, which is easily done with eloquent.

Comment: i want to show course_name from the pivot table with category name from categorie model and the classe name from classe model the classe model does not contain the catgeory name

Comment: Property [classe_name] does not exist on this collection instance

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help i found the solution

```
$categories=Course_category::with('classe')->get();
```

and i use loop inside loop for the collection

```
@foreach ($categories as $item)
            {{-- {{$item->course_category->category_name}} --}}
              @foreach ($item->classe as $cat)
                  {{$cat->course_name}}
                  {{$cat->classe_name}}
              @endforeach
            @endforeach
```